# htaccess URL Rewrite for blog

Tags: .htaccess

I'm having an issue trying to get my htaccess to work properly

I'm custom building my website, but have not figured out how to get the blog posts to show right.

My base URL is working for the pages. Example: mywebsite.com/contact

But I'm trying to get the blog posts to work like this. mywebsite.com/posts/post-title-here

Here is my htaccess, and I've commented out methods I've tried. But not fully understanding what I'm doing wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [QSA,NC,L]

#RewriteRule ^posts/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ view-post.php?id=$2
#RewriteRule ^posts/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    view-post.php?slug=$1    [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^posts/(.*)$ view-post.php?slug=$1
#RewriteRule  ^posts/(.+)$ view-post.php?title=$1   [L]

Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post this above your index.php line in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?posts/(.*) view-blog.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these on your htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]*)$ view-post.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]*)$ view-post.php?title=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried this, but it still doesn't work, though.